# How do I parse an nxml file?

Tags: java, python, xml, parsing, nxml

I have no Idea about nxml format although I know how to parse xml files. When I open [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B69eBNglp2NrTUM1cERDanhMVVE) file in sublime it appears something like this. I would really appreciate if someone could guide me on python/java parser.

[image]

Comment: I've never heard of nxml.  This looks like plain XML to me.  What is different?

Comment: How do i parse it?, like dom parser is available for xml in python

Comment: Then you could use that dom parser or any XML parser.  Both Java and Python have plenty of XML parsers.

Comment: Well, I turned out to be same for nxml. I should have tried to once with xml parser first. Anyways thanks @Pace